# how to resize image in Laravel and save data in database at the same time

Tags: php, laravel, image, store, image-resizing

i'm trying to pass data(title,description and resized image) to my database

this is the store function, for now it saves my images in that path but it doesn't save them in the database

the store function can work if i remove the resize image.

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required',
        'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg,gif,svg|max:10240',
        'description' => 'required',
    ]);

    $path = $request->file('image');
    $filename = $path->getClientOriginalName();
    $image_resize = Image::make($path->getRealPath()); 
    $image_resize->resize(800, 800);             
    $image_resize->save(public_path('images/' .$filename));

    $post = new Post;

    $post->title = $request->title;
    $post->description = $request->description;
    $post->image = $image_resize;

    $post->save();

 
    return redirect()->route('posts.index')
                    ->with('success','Post has been created successfully.');
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yb75u.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwGuE.png)

this is the new store function

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required',
        'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg,gif,svg|max:10240',
        'description' => 'required',
    ]);

    $path = $request->file('image');
    $filename = $path->getClientOriginalName();
    $image_resize = Image::make($path->getRealPath()); 
    $image_resize->resize(800, 800);             
    $image_resize->save(public_path('images/' .$filename));

    $post = new Post;

    $post->title = $request->title;
    $post->description = $request->description;
    $post->image = 'images/' .$filename;

    $post->save();

 
    return redirect()->route('posts.index')
                    ->with('success','Post has been created successfully.');
}
```

this the blade code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Laravel 8 CRUD Tutorial</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
</head>
<body>

<div class="container mt-2">

<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 margin-tb">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <h2>Laravel 8 Post CRUD Tutorial</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right mb-2">
                <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('posts.create') }}"> Create New Post</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   
    @if ($message = Session::get('success'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <p>{{ $message }}</p>
        </div>
    @endif
   
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th>S.No</th>
            <th>Image</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th width="280px">Action</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach ($posts as $post)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $post->id }}</td>
            <td><img src="{{ Storage::url($post->image) }}" height="75" width="75" alt="" /></td>
            <td>{{ $post->title }}</td>
            <td>{{ $post->description }}</td>
            <td>
                <form action="{{ route('posts.destroy',$post->id) }}" method="POST">
    
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('posts.edit',$post->id) }}">Edit</a>
   
                    @csrf
                    @method('DELETE')
      
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </table>
  
    {!! $posts->links() !!}

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: which type is "image" column in the database?

Answer (score 0):

put file name in mysql not image object !!!!!

```
$post->image = "images/$filename";
```

Comment: the image type in the database is VARCHAR